# Use curl to download list of files in csv

Tags: bash, url, curl

I have a csv of JPG url extensions.

```
http://www.example.com/images/[url_extension]
```

I want to use curl to loop through the CSV and download the jpg at each extension. So far I have the following, but I'm struggling with syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=urlextensions.csv

while read line
do
outfile=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; {print $NF}')
curl -o "$http://www.example.com/images/" "$line" 
done < "$/Users/Me/Documents/urlextensions.csv"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

1. You define `file` in line 2, but then you don't use it in the loop.
2. Putting `$` in front of things will make the shell try to substitute it which probably isn't what you want when you do `$http` or `$/Users`.
3. You define `outfile` in your loop, but you don't use it.  Maybe you meant to put it after the `-o` on your curl line.
4. The `-o` argument to curl should be a filename, but you put the URL there.
5. The base URL (`http://www.example.com/images`) and the part you add to it need to be in the same argument, not separated by a space which will make the shell think it takes two arguments.

So I end up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=./extensions.txt

while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo downloading $line
    curl -o $line "http://example.com/$line"
done < "$filename"
```

If you put that in a file name `read_examp` and make it executable you can see it work like:

```
chicks$ cat extensions.txt 
foo
bar
baz
chicks$ ./read_examp 
foo
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1270  100  1270    0     0  41794      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 42333
bar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1270  100  1270    0     0  53987      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55217
baz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1270  100  1270    0     0  48366      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48846
chicks$ ls -l `cat extensions.txt`
-rw-r--r--  1 chicks  staff  1270 Oct  7 10:01 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 chicks  staff  1270 Oct  7 10:01 baz
-rw-r--r--  1 chicks  staff  1270 Oct  7 10:01 foo
```

Note: you mention CSV's but your example code does not seem to deal with that at all.  You can extend this with something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/bash-shell-scripting-csv-parsing) to pull a field out of your CSV instead of using the whole line.

Comment: chicks—Thank you for taking the time to explain problems with my script and then show a working example. Really, really helps with the learning process. Greatly appreciated. Using your script, I was able to achieve what I needed.